# LINQ to SQL - Exception ao dar sum() em uma query que contém outra subquery usando LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
    private decimal GetBankAccountCashierTotal()
    {
        var company = _context.Company.FirstOrDefault();

        return _context.PersonBankAgencyAccount
               .Where(p => p.PersonID.Equals(company.PersonID))
               .Where(c => c.BankAgencyAccountBalance
                    .Any(b => b.Reference <= DateTime.Now))
               .Select(x => x.BankAgencyAccountBalance
                    .Where(d => d.Reference.Date <= DateTime.Now)
                    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Reference)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .CurrentBalance)
                    .sum();

    }
```

este é o meu método completo, na chamada deste método tenho uma exception

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code"

e no output

> "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler:Error: An
>   exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a
>   query. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate
>   function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: Qual é o erro? Provavelmente precisa ver o que vem antes no código pra ver o que está faltando fazer.

Answer (score 1):

É o banco que não aceita esse tipo de comando mesmo, se vc escrever um select dando sum em uma subquery, vai dar essa mensagem.

Tem que escrever a consulta diferente, eu faria uma consulta com group by das informações da subquery, e então faria join com a consulta principal.

pode fazer uma consulta como essa para pegar o registro pela maior data

```
var consultaPorData = from a in precos
                    where a.IdFilial == 53
                    group a by new { a.IdProduto, a.PrecoVendaProduto } into g                                      
                    select new
                    {
                        Produto = g.Key.IdProduto,
                        valor = g.Key.PrecoVendaProduto,
                        data = g.Max(e=>e.DataPreco)
                    };
```